# Error when importing sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, python-3.6

I'm trying to download sklearn for a AI project of mine. I on Windows 10 wiht PyCharm. Python 3.6.2. I have already downloaded sklearn which turned out just fine but when I run the program, it says that I need to install scipy, numpy and .base. The error:

```
D:\python.exe C:/Users/coder/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/starting.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/coder/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/starting.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn as tree
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
from .base import clone
 File "D:\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

So I went to the terminal in used pip to install scipy and this happens.

```
C:\Users\coder\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
   Complete output from command d:\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\coder\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rzd5yfdo\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-xpk934rd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:lib', 'C:\\', 'd:libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['d:lib', 'C:\\', 'd:libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
  pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['d:lib', 'C:\\', 'd:libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rzd5yfdo\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rzd5yfdo\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rzd5yfdo\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
Command "d:\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\coder\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rzd5yfdo\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-xpk934rd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rzd5yfdo\scipy\
```

Do you know how to fix this error? I just want to use sklearn!! lol *nervous laughing*

Comment: pip3 install sklearn

Comment: pip3 install scipy

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: do you run the cmd as admin ?

Comment: yes, i did. coder is admin.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I had to use Anaconda to import the modules into PyCharm.